# Cannot add SourceSafe Database as Visual Studio 2010 source control

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-sourcesafe

My issue is that I cannot add SourceSafe Database for source control within Visual Studio 2010.

Our team was initially using VSS for source control in Visual Studio 2010.   During an evaluation of TFS, I switched my source control to TFS. It will be a few weeks before a decision is made on TFS, so I needed to switch my source control back to VSS.   However I'm now unable to add a SourceSafe Database in Visual Studio.

Steps to Reproduce in Visual Studio 2010:
1) Access the 'Open SourceSafe Database' form via Tools->Options->Source Control->Plug-in Settings-->Advanced
or via File->Source Control
2) The list of available database is blank so I choose 'Browse'.
3) I browse to the srcsafe.ini file for my VSS database and select it.
4) I'm promted to confirm the Database Name - Click OK.
5) The database does not appear in the 'Open SourceSafe' Database form.  The list of available databases is still blank.

Note that I can add the database fine outside of Visual Studio using VSS directly.   However the databases I add via VSS do not appear in the Visual Studio forms.

I'm suspicious that this is related to "down-grading" from TFS to VSS which may not have been heavily tested at MS.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that my VS installation was corrupted.  I do believe there is a bug in VS 2010 which does not allow me to use VSS for source control after having used TFS.   Fortunately for me, our team decided to go forward with TFS for our project's source control.   I never had to solve the problem.   I believe that reinstalling Visual Studio alone would have been enough to solve the issue.

Answer (score 9):

I installed VS2010, then i install VSS, then i have the same problem, cant connect to my VSS it by default opens (TFS)

the suggestion here, to reinstall, dont sound good, did a bit more searching and found this:-
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssourcecontrol/thread/6c927805-bca6-445b-b406-0a0da8fa21d3

and found the easy solution that 'CletusLoomis' is looking for:

simply:-
hanks for your post.

Could you please try the following steps?

1. Open VS2010, then choose the menu: Tools->Options, then click "Souce Control"
2. click drop-down box under text"Current souce control plug-in", use "None", rather than "Microsoft Visual Source Safe"

thats it, problem solved!
:)

hope this helps someone else who found this page via google.

Answer (score 4):

To do that you must run Visual Studio 2010 as Administrator. Just click on Icon using right button, Go to Properties, Compatibility, at the botton of screen you should mark Run this program as administrator.

That's all.
Must exist some file that the permission should be granted to all users, but instead of searching for the file, I preffer this solution.

Regards,

Luiz Ricci

Answer (score 4):

My Visual Studio 2010 had very similar symptoms: having selected Visual SourceSafe 2005 in the Options I had the only menu option: `Launch Microsoft SourceSafe`

While following the steps provided by 'visual' (as of Nov 30 '10 at 8:00) I have found the following registry key, which needs to be switched to 0 to enable the SourceSafe menu options to be displayed in Visual Studio 2010. Once the registry key value has been changed to zero Visual Studio needs to be restarted and .. voila! Now I have an additional menu option `Open from source control..`.

The registry key is as follows (for 32bit OS it would need to be slightly modified): `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\SourceSafe\Namespace Extension\DisableOpenFromSourceControl`

Now, why it was disabled by default is beyond me.

Answer (score 2):

Your installation of VS might be corrupted. I would recommend uninstalling VSS, VS, and TFS and then reinstalling VS and VSS. Unfortunately, this could take 4+ hours, but it should fix your issue.

Comment: The VSS option(s) were missing in VS for me - thankfully I was able to get away with uninstalling and reinstalling VSS only :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010 and VSS. I noticed several things:

1. VSS as standalone program does always work on my system.
2. VSS works perfectly in my projects, if the UAC Level is the lowest, but not with the default UAC Level.

If I open a project file with VSS source control, Visual Studio tries to read the registry. It fails to read/write the keys in the registry with access denied. Therefore I changed the permissions in the registry of the SourceSafe keys to full access for all users. Now, VSS works perfectly on my system with default UAC security level.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and my projects added to Visual SourceSafe 6.0
The VSS database list was not prompted on my machine as well.

After a number of attempts for over 3 hours. Finally got a solution.

I run the VS2010 using Run As Administrator option. The VSS database list was visble.

I think the issue might be due to Access Rights of Registry in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

What a nightmare this has been. Ultimately, you can set in domain or local policy.

Local Security Policy\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode - Disabled

This means anyone in the administrator group does not have to have approval (The Dreaded Run as Administrator)to be an administrator. Can be set locally as above or domain wide. Solved a lot of problems for us.

Answer (score 0):

Options -> Source Control -> Make sure the "Current Source Control Plugin" is correctly set.

Mine was set to Microsoft Visual Source Safe (Internet), and should have been Microsoft Visual Source Safe.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you can view the database by visual source safe explorer.
Then, trying to proceed with these step...

1. Open Visual studio as Administrator.
2. Log in visual source safe by the database path. (it still disappears the database in "Available database" list.)